# Loading one table in MySQL is ridiculously slow

Tags: mysql

Fro clarity all other tables in the DB work as expected, and load ~2million rows in a fraction of a second. The one table of just ~600 rows is taking 10+minutes to load in navcat.

I can't think of any possible reason for this. There are just 4 columns. One of them **is** a large text field, but I've worked with large text fields before and they've never been this slow.

running `explain select * from parser_queue` I get

```
 id  setect type  table     type  possible keys  key  key len  ref  rows  extra
 1   SIMPLE    parser_queue  ALL  -              -    -        -    658   -
```

The profile tells me that 453 seconds are spent 'sending data'
I've also got this in the 'Status' tab. I don't understand most of it, but these numbers are much higher than my other tables.

```
Bytes_received            31
Bytes_sent                32265951
Com_select                1
Created_tmp_files         16
Handler_read_rnd_next     659
Key_read_requests         9018487
Key_reads                 3928
Key_write_requests        310431
Key_writes                4290
Qcache_hits               135077
Qcache_inserts            14289
Qcache_lowmem_prunes      4133
Qcache_queries_in_cache   983
Questions                 1
Select_scan               1
Table_locks_immediate     31514
```

The data stored in the text field is about 12000 chars on average.
There is a primary, auto increment `int` id field, a `tinyint` status field, a `text` field, and a `timestamp` field with `on update current timestamp`.

---

OK I will try out both answers, but I can answer the questions quickly first:

Primary key on the ID field is the only key. This table is used for queuing, with ~50 records added/deleted per hour, but I only created it yesterday. Could it become corrupted in such a short time?

It is MyISAM

---

More work trying to isolate the problem:

`repair table` did nothing
`optimize table` did nothing
created a temp table. queries were about 50% slower on the temp table.

Deleted the table and rebuilt it. `SELECT *` takes 18 seconds with just *4 rows*.

Here is the SQL I used to create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `parser_queue` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `status` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `data` text NOT NULL,
  `last_updated` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

Stranger still, everything seems fine on my local box. The slowness only happens on the dev site.

For clarity: there are more than 100 tables on the dev site and this is the *only one* that is funky.

---

OK I have disabled all cron jobs which use this table. `SHOW PROCESSLIST` does not reveal any locks on the table.

Changing the engine to `InnoDB` did not produce any significant improvement (86 seconds vs 94 for MyISAM)

any other ideas? . . .

Running `SHOW PROCESSLIST` during the query reveals it spends most of its time `writing to net`

Comment: `18 seconds with just 4 rows`, wow! Is it possible that some other query is locking the table? Have you tried using InnoDB instead of MyISAM for this table?

Comment: Have you tried locking (with Read Lock) the table and then running the SELECT? What is the setting of the `concurrent_insert` variable?

Comment: Let us know if turning the engine into InnoDB helps the problem.

Comment: @Pentium10 no luck with InnoDB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you suspect corruption somewhere, you can try either (or both) of the following:

```
CREATE TABLE temp SELECT * FROM parser_queue;
```

This will create a new table "identical" to the previous one, except it will be recreated. Alternatively (or maybe after you've made a copy), you can try:

```
REPAIR TABLE parser_queue;
```

You may also want to try optimizing the table; it might have gotten fragmented since you are using it as a queue.

```
OPTIMIZE TABLE parser_queue;
```

You can determine if the table is fragmented by running `SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'Data_Free'` and see if this produces a high number.

**Update**

You say you are storing `gzcompress`ed data in the `TEXT` columns. Try changing the `TEXT` column to `BLOB` instead, which is meant to handle binary data, such as compressed text.

Comment: Tried your suggestions with, sadly, no avail. More details added to the question.

Comment: Added a new suggestion for you... :)

Comment: Changing to `BLOB` cut the query time by 75%. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1):

The name gives away that you are using the table for queueing (lots of inserts and delets, maybe?). Maybe you have had the table a while and it's heavily fragmented. If my assumptions are correct, try `OPTIMIZE TABLE parser_queue;`

You can read more about this in the manual:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/optimize-table.html

Answer (score 1):

Right, the problem seems to have been only this: the `text` fields where too huge.

Running

```
 SELECT id, status, last_updated FROM parser_queue
```

takes less time than

```
 SELECT data FROM parser_queue WHERE id = 6
```

Since all the queries I will be running return only one row, the slowdown will not affect me so much. I'm already using `gzcompress` on the data stored, so I don't think there is much more I could do anyway.